# query to search a particular word/string in toad/oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I trying to find out a word/string named 'audapro_ind' in oracle database in toad. This word can be present anywhere in column of table, function, procedure etc. in oracle database

I tried few queries like

```
select name , line,text from dba_source where upper(text) like 
upper ('audapro_ind') escape '\'
```

also

```
select DISTINCT(name) from user_source where type = 'PROCEDURE'
 AND text_like 'audapro_ind'
```

But  could not able to find the solution

Comment: You need to use a wildcard with `LIKE`. `select name , line,text from dba_source where upper(text) like 
'%AUDAPRO_IND%'; ` for example

Comment: I would recommend an OracleDB Manual for reading.

Comment: Some versions of TOAD have an object search that will allow you to search in any package,procedure, trigger, table definition (not the data)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
select name , line,text from dba_source where regexp_like(text,'audapro_ind','i');
```

'i' specifies case-insensitive matching.